# Convert type 'Object' to 'Int'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe that is an 'object' and all the values in this column are surrounded by brackets, like this:

```
|payment|
|-------|
|[561]  |
|[541]  |
|[141]  |
|[525]  |
```

I would like to erase the brackets and then turn my column into an integer!
Please help!!! Thanks in advance.

```
(df['payment'].replace('[', '', regex=True )
               .replace(']', '',   regex=True ).astype(float))
```

```
df['payment'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

Comment: How was this dataframe created?  It LOOKS like your columns contain one-element lists instead of integers, and that suggests it was not created properly.

Comment: If lists, use `df['payment'].str[0]`

Comment: @mozway If it's a list, why are you converting it to a string with `.str`?

Comment: @Barmar this doesn't convert to string, this uses the str accessor to slice ;)

Comment: @mozway wouldn't it be best if the OP used `extract` instead?

Comment: I made this column by grouping another dataframe with the function 'unique'

Comment: @Mateo what is the output of `df['payment'].to_dict()`? And what was the code/data used to generate this dictionary?

Comment: @mozway it creates a dictionary with all my dataframe

Comment: I know, I want to see the content for debugging

Comment: The problem is that I used the 'unique' function while aggregating.. but the original data was a float64 and after using 'unique' it returns an object

Comment: We need to know that data type of the `payment` column. Can you edit the question with what `type(df["payment"].iloc[0])` returns?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df['payment'] = df['payment'].str.strip('[]').astype(int)
```